# Problems using Android TimePicker.getCurrentHour

Tags: java, android

I'm making an app that utilizes a TimePicker, and this is my first time using it. My code is as follows:

```
final Dialog mTimeDialog = new Dialog(this);
TimePicker timePicker = (TimePicker)mTimeDialog.findViewById(R.id.timePicker);
TimePicker timePicker1 = (TimePicker)mTimeDialog.findViewById(R.id.timePicker1);
int starthour = timePicker.getCurrentHour();
int startminute = timePicker.getCurrentMinute();
int finishhour = timePicker1.getCurrentHour();
int finishminute = timePicker1.getCurrentMinute();
```

But I'm getting an exception when I try to run it. When I push the save button that triggers the `onClick` that this is contained in, I get this:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
 at com.csam.hourtracker.hourentry.onClick(hourentry.java:40)
```

Any help would be great!

Comment: what is line 40 `hourentry.java`?

Comment: Line 40 is int starthour = timePicker.getCurrentHour(); sorry, should've specified that.

Comment: your `timePicker` is null

Comment: do you have a custom layout for you dialog?

Comment: post the layout where you have your timerpicker's

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the below

```
final Dialog mTimeDialog = new Dialog(this);
TimePicker timePicker = (TimePicker)mTimeDialog.findViewById(R.id.timePicker);
```

You have not set the content of layout to Dialog before initializing the TimerPicker's

You are missing

```
mTimeDialog.setContentView(yourview);
```

Hence your timepicker's are null causing NPE.

`findViewById` looks for a view with the id mentioned in the current infalted layout. I believe you have a custom layout for your dialog. You need to inflate the layout first and then initialize your views.

Comment: Thanks! Just adding the setContentView fixed that problem. I'm now having other problems... but hopefully I can fix them.

Comment: @dacelbot post a new question with relevant details. if i can i will surely help